# Fixed x-axis in Highcharts Stock (stop auto-scaling)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In the chart when it start drawing main series (LTP), It draws on whole width.

[image: chart]

Is there a way to draw it just like the selector chart at bottom?

EDIT : I want entire xAxis viewable and then add the points without auto-scaling the xAxis.

Have a look at my code

http://jsfiddle.net/S9SwB/9/

Comment: You mean have the entire xAxis viewable and then add the points without auto-scaling the xAxis?

Comment: Well, I modified your fiddle to use xAxis max and it still did not do what I thought it would. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/f6SmR/

Comment: posted another solution, If the answer helped, please vote/mark it accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build up on @wergeld's solution here, as you see in his solution, the end of x-axis was position correctly at 5:30 but there was a suddent leap in time, this is because the ordinal property of the axis is set to true by default, which means all points are equally spaced in terms of pixels, immaterial of difference in terms of time, so the axis leaves enough room at right for just 1 point, and hence number of pixels required to add one point. On setting ordinal to false, it will allocate as much space as is needed based on time difference.
All in all, here goes your solution :) http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/UP5sW/

```
var min = new Date().getTime();
var max = min + 50 * 500;  
//...

xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
        max:max
    },
    series: [
        {
        name: 'Series 0',
        data: [[min, 0]]
    },
    {
        name: 'End',
        data: [[max, 0]]
    }]
```

More about ordinal option @ http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#xAxis--ordinal & http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/ordinal-false/

Comment: Your fiddles don't work anymore. Avoid externally hosted libraries which stop working after a while while sharing public fiddles like these. http://code.jugal.me/js/jugalsLib.js - 404

Comment: I think the code is more important then the libraries, the thirdparty lib was used only for reducing code. All the important code still remains in the fiddle. @Mrchief

Comment: If that's the case, then you should highlight the relevant piece in your answer and let the fiddle have entire thing. A broken fiddle is just bad!

Comment: @Mrchief added a code snippet in the answer too. Links sometime do get broken, but for a person who really wants the answer, the code in the fiddle was still there, there was no logical error (it just couldn't fetch the referenced file), you can't always have control to all links you post, that doesn't entitle others down voting without even trying to have a look at the answer. Accepted answers do mean it worked at the time of posting.

Comment: And that is why it is a bad idea to have those external links. Include the configuration - its no big deal and only makes your solution complete. Don't assume every reader to be a highcharts pro.

Comment: @mrchief there was nothing in the jsfiddle that required one to be a pro, there is enough explanation in the answer to not really require any more code, and definitely not bad enough to be downvoted. Just coz u got lazy and felt like having some sort of controversory to brighten up ur sorry life, i am wasting my time. Go get a life, Adios

Comment: You're stubborn! Instead of "judging" people, how about you make your answer work? If there is noting in the fiddle, then edit your answer to remove the fiddle. If you do include it, make sure it works. I'll remove the downvote the moment your fiddle works again.

Comment: IMHO you're equally stubborn. You could have politely left a comment and I would have been happy to add code, down vote made me furious,btw I do try to add code in my answers where necessary.As for removing the fiddle, the links point to my site which is down due to the host's issues, this is just an intermittent problem, which I am expecting to be resolved by the weekend. Anyway thanks for your suggestion. And jsFiddle is just a demo, the answer is all here on SO with reference links.What about all the java/c++/etc answers than can never have a demo? will you down vote them all too? @Mrchief

Comment: @Mrchief my site is back up like I had promised, and all the fiddles work now too

Comment: Thx for letting this miserable low-life know. I've definitely become more popular than ever after this controversy!