# HighCharts Animation By Column

Tags: animation, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to control the timing of the animations for each piece of data in HighCharts?

What I mean is that on SLIDE 7 of the following demo: http://blackwavedesign.com/tmp/drlathian/animation_demo/index.html I was hoping to have the first column animate, then 5 seconds later, have the second column animate, and so forth. I'm thinking that there is probably not a way to do this, but maybe someone knows of a workaround. The script that creates this chart is in the buildHighCharts.js function of this script: http://blackwavedesign.com/tmp/drlathian/animation_demo/assets/js/drutil.js

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by having an initial point on your chart and then pumping in your additional points on an interval.
See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/nY7ve/16/) as an example.

Comment: Nice one, Wergeld. @svanetten you can combine the above answer with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949156/fixed-x-axis-in-highcharts-stock-stop-auto-scaling/11784430#11784430 to get what you desire

Comment: Correct, @JugalThakkar, I am not handling the data labels here and he probably wants the chart width and point placement static. This was just a quick way to do it with code I already had lying around. Pushing data for animation events is much cleaner and gives you more control.